# Installing SSL on Apache 2.x - self-signed errror

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, certificate

So I bought an SSL cert from GoDaddy and followed their instructions on how to get it signed, and downloaded and installed it. It's not working. It says the SSL certificate was self-signed and the common name is "SomeOrganization" even though I entered all the information correctly in the CSR.

Here are the lines in my vhost conf file:

```
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl/domain.com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl/domain.com.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl/gd_bundle.crt
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? mod_ssl is enabled in apache and I'm running on CentOS 6. Any help would be appreciated as I need to get this working today.

**--UPDATE--**

I figured it out, and I feel pretty dumb about it now.

I was adding those SSL lines to the `<VirtualHost *:80>` directive.  I took that directive and made a copy of it, but changed it to `<VirtualHost *:443>` and it's working perfectly now.

I guess it's good to learn it now so I don't make the same dumb mistake in the future.  Hopefully someone else can benefit from this as well.

Comment: Please put the way you solved your issue in an answer and mark it as accepted, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, it wouldn't let me add an answer for 10 hours so I thought I'd put it in the original post instead.  It won't let me accept the answer for 19 more hours so I'll come back and mark it as accepted tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, and I feel pretty dumb about it now.

I was adding those SSL lines to the `<VirtualHost *:80>` directive. I took that directive and made a copy of it, but changed it to `<VirtualHost *:443>` for the SSL port and it's working perfectly now.